# How to use awk to chop and compare string?

Tags: regex, url, awk

I want to use awk to filter lines in a big file.

Basiclly I need to check if the url is in a specific url domain. Such as http://example.com/test in the domain of example.com.

I think I need to chop the url string by "//" and "." then compare the url string.

How can I get the domain from a url using awk and compare it in case insensitive situation?

Comment: Why `awk` rather than, say, `grep`? Which platform — Linux (GNU `grep`) or other (not GNU `grep`)?

Comment: I need other information in that file, not only url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
echo "http://example.com/test
https://foo.com/test/index.html" | awk '
{
    gsub(".*://","");

    gsub("[^.]+",""); # comment out if you want to leave subdomains 
    gsub("/.*$","");
    name=tolower($1);
    printf("name=%s : ",name);
    if(name ~ "example.com")
        printf("match !\n");
    else
        printf("Does not match !\n");
}'
```

To answer Johnathan Leffler's comment, here is an enhanced version that strips out subdomains if any and detects non qualified names:

```
echo "http://example.com/test
http://www.example.com/test
ftp://localhost/test
https://foo.com/test/index.html" | awk '
{
  gsub(".*://","",$1)
  gsub("/.*$","",$1)
  name=tolower($1)
  c=split(name,dc,".")
  if(c>=2)
    domain=dc[c-1]"."dc[c]
  else
    domain=""
  printf("name=%16s : ",name)
  printf("domain=%16s : ",domain)
  if(domain ~ "example.com")
    printf("match !\n")
  else
    printf("Does not match !\n")
}'
```

It outputs:

```
name=     example.com : domain=     example.com : match !
name= www.example.com : domain=     example.com : match !
name=       localhost : domain=                 : Does not match !
name=         foo.com : domain=         foo.com : Does not match !
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Answer updated, thanks for pointing out this issue !